# How to overlay 2 elements over image

Tags: css, flexbox, overlay

In my photographic portfolio, I display a series of images of different ratio in tracks that automatically fill the width of the display.  That is working perfectly... after receiving some help.

My ultimate objective is to permanently display a little heart over the top-left corner of each image AND display a semitransparent strip over the bottom of each image containing the caption only on mouseover the image.

I have almost achieved that result but I can not figure out after hours of trying how to overlay the 2 elements as explained above... so for now trhey are together on top of the image... which is not optimal.

So I would appreciate some help to achieve that result if possible.

Here is part of the code in question and a sample can be found on my website : [TwoOverlaysOnImage](https://www.paulgodard.com/collections.html?Collection=search&String=test).

CSS code

```
.my-flex-item {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    border: 2px solid #1d1d1d;
    height: 100px;
}

.img-holder {
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block;
}

.img-holder p {
    position: absolute; 
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left !important;
    font-size: 0.7em !important;
    width: 100%;
}

.img-holder:hover > p {
    background-color: rgba(60,60,60,0.7);
    text-align: center !important;
}

.img-holder span {
    margin-top:40px;
    color: white !important;
    left: 30px;
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-content-center">

    <div class="img-holder">
        <p>
            <img src="heart0.png" style="margin-left:6px; margin-top:4px;"/>
            <span class="thumbCaption">caption</span>
        </p>
        <a href="modal...">
            <img class="my-flex-item" src="imagepath..." alt="caption..." />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add a working example? Without it, all I can say is use `position: absolute` on the heart and `position: relative` on the container, then use `top` and `left` to position it

Comment: Please include a [MRE] so we can see what you are doing in the js functions - this is where you are adding the caption so we need to see that too :)

Comment: Thank you.  In fact the js is not the problem here.  I have edited my original question so the code provided is a full sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

html:

```
 <div style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <div id="img-cont" class="img-cont">
        <img class="heart" src="path/to/heart/icon">
        <div class = "hover">
                <p>Sample Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-cont{
    position: relative;
    width: 420px;
    height: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588876315093-ce09afb34028?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80")
}

.img-cont .heart{
    position: absolute;
    color: white; 
    top: 15px; 
    left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hover{
    clip-path: url(#img-cont);
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.img-cont:hover .hover{
    height: 50%;
}

.hover p{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that but this will not work (background image with fixed width) as it need to work for a series of images with different width in the track.  See the example provided on my website : https://www.paulgodard.com/collections.html?Collection=search&String=test